and you are still saying nice things about them
a. You know they hate you, and you still say nice things about them.
b. You know they hate you, and you are still saying nice things about them.
c. You know they hate you, and you say nice things about them still.
d. You know they hate you, and you are saying nice things about them still.
In which of the above sentences does 'still' have a temporal meaning and in which does it mean 'and even so', 'and in spite of that'?
Many thanks

There is no good answer because none of your four has a single meaning of still outside context. Pretty much everything pretty much always depends on context.

It'll depend on stress and intonation.

The present tense in your examples (say, are saying) indicates that the saying of nice things about them was not confined to the past but is ongoing: "You continue to say nice things about them".
Since the two clauses are coordinated with and (not "but" nor "yet") there is an express temporal meaning and only an implied concessive meaning with still.

Agreed - I think the only order of words which would definitely imply the concessive meaning is "...and still you're saying nice things about them".

@KateBunting Yes, that placement has far greater force.
